# How to remove water spots?

Tags: cleaning, bathroom, water, glass

I have a shower with a glass screen to stop the water covering the floor and I try to wipe it down every time using a [squeegee](http://www.amazon.co.uk/GBPro-Window-Squeegee-Stainless-Steel/dp/B00454CG04) in order to prevent the exact problem I am having - I believe the issue is to other people in the house not wiping down after use. So the inevitable has happened and it has lots of water spots all over it and it doesn't seem to matter how much window / glass cleaner I use and how much scrubbing with a cloth, it does not go - at least, not without some considerable effort on my part.

> **Does anyone know any easy solutions for removing water spot stains from glass / windows?**

As I mentioned I have tried using a spray - [Mr Muscle Daily Shower Shine Shower Cleaner](http://www.mysupermarket.co.uk/asda-compare-prices/Household_Cleaning/Mr_Muscle_Shower_Shine_Daily_Shower_Cleaner_500ml.html) - and I have tried a couple of methods:

- Leaving it on to soak
- Scrubbing with a [sponge scrubber](http://shopping.rediff.com/product/set-of-5-sponge-scourer--dish-scrubber/12910259)
- Using water to combat water

Alas - to no avail.

Comment: Down votes? Any reason

Comment: *upvotes* ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

Answer (score 4, accepted):

White vinegar, half and half with water, or neat, should shift the spots, but even better, a glass of white wine rubbed over, will get them off and leave a good shine, though in my experience, the cheaper the wine the better (you're also less likely to drink it instead!)

Answer (score 3):

**WD-40**
WD-40 has been known to be a good cleaner for mirrors and windows with water spots - just apply a bit to the area and run off with a cloth and it should be shiny and clean! [There are also many other uses for WD-40 if you are interested!](http://www.wisebread.com/almost-2000-uses-for-a-can-of-wd-40-1)

**Vinegar and baking powder**
If you mix a 1/4 cup of vinegar with equal amounts of baking powder to create a paste, apply to afflicted area and leave to dry for a short while and rinse off with a damp cloth.

**Rub down with newspaper**
I read that rubbing down the area with warm water and using black a white newspaper as the cloth will help to remove the stubborn spots! [Here's a link for more information on that, and some other methods!](http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Hard-Water-Stains-From-Glass)

Comment: Not sure about the newspaper - I use it to buff up the windows after washing, works really well, but I'm not convinced it'd get limescale spots off.

Comment: WD-40 do the trick!