# How to clean mirror without leaving paper towel specks behind

Tags: cleaning, bathroom

When I clean a mirror with glass cleaner and a paper towel, I see a bunch of little specks left by the paper towel.  I've tried using hand wipes and newspaper, but they both seem to do the same thing.  Is there something else I can use that doesn't leave stuff behind?

Comment: Don't use a paper towel :-)  I just use a regular towel.

Comment: Um. Related, possible duplicate: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7171/how-to-clean-glass-without-glass-cleaner?rq=1

Comment: Or possibly this one: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/4434/how-to-remove-water-spots?rq=1

Comment: @Mithrandir: My question is about the dust specks, not water spots.

Comment: A piece of cotton material is best, anything like polycotton from old sheets or cotton shirts, they're worth cutting up just to use as glass cleaning cloths, everything else leaves a residue of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a regular cloth, such as a towel or even a T-shirt. Rub on the spot that needs attention (I do it in circles), and soon your spots wll disappear.

Answer (score 3):

Believe it or not, newspaper is really great for cleaning windows and not leaving streaks. You can either just use the newspaper with your cleaner, or you can wipe the window with the newspaper afterwards. You can wad it or fold it.

Answer (score 1):

Use liquid handsoap,  rub onto mirror and use the palm of your hand to move it in circles until the entire mirror is white and creamy,  then use a regular hand towel and slide from left  to right  once , then move to the next clean part of the towel and do the next left to right strip.

Don't worry about the little white line left between strips,  do these after the mirror is completed.

I usually do this each time I'm changing hand towel in bathroom. It's gives superior result compared to any other method I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could use table salt along with tissue paper to clean and then use a drop of water at last so as to remove the leftovers too.

Answer (score -1):

Try a coffee filter, lint-free paper towel, or a microfiber cloth.

Comment: Two microfibres, one damp, one dry, for best results.